# Python Xlrd and Xlwt

Tags: python

I have the following content in an old Excel sheet:

[image: excel sheet screenshot]

I need to generate a new Excel sheet with the following values:

[image: excel sheet updated]

In the input Excel file's 3rd column I have a range `10010-10040` and an increment value of `10`. This needs to be expanded in my new Excel file.

If I give a comma (,) in between values, it should be treated as separate values and expanded. (Like in row2, column 3)

I have no idea how to do this and I am new to Python.

Comment: You need to separate the value "10010-10040-10" ("initNumber-FinalNumber-Increment") using the character  "-" as the division. Then you can perform a for loop (or something similar) where your increment will be the "Increment" and start at "initNumber" and finish at "FinalNumber". Inside your cycle you concatenate "Ex" + iterationNumber to get Ex1, Ex2, .... 
For the 3rd column you can have a variable that starts at "initNumber" and adds "Increment" every loop.

Comment: Are you dealing with old `xls` files? Or the newer `xlsx` files? These libraries are designed to work with the older format.

Comment: Hi Martin.. I used new xlsx file as the input file. xlrd works with it. The output file came out as a old format xls file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following. This uses the `xlrd` and `xlwt` libraries to read and write `xls` spreadsheets:

```
import xlrd
import xlwt

wb_in = xlrd.open_workbook(r'input.xls')
sheet_name = wb_in.sheet_names()[0]
ws_in = wb_in.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)

wb_out = xlwt.Workbook()
ws_out = wb_out.add_sheet(sheet_name)   # Use the same sheet name

row_out = 0

for row_in in range(ws_in.nrows):
    row = ws_in.row_values(row_in)

    if isinstance(row[2], float):
        req_spec = str(int(row[2]))
    else:
        req_spec = row[2]

    req_range = req_spec.split('-')
    req_enum = req_spec.split(',')

    if len(req_range) > 1:    # e.g. 10010-10040-10
        for value in range(int(str(req_range[0])), int(str(req_range[1])) + 1, int(str(req_range[2]))):
            ws_out.write(row_out, 0, row[0])
            ws_out.write(row_out, 1, row[1])
            ws_out.write(row_out, 2, str(value))
            row_out += 1
    elif len(req_enum) > 1:    # e.g. 1010,1020
        for value in req_enum:
            ws_out.write(row_out, 0, row[0])
            ws_out.write(row_out, 1, row[1])
            ws_out.write(row_out, 2, value)
            row_out += 1
    else:                      # e.g. 10100
        ws_out.write(row_out, 0, row[0])
        ws_out.write(row_out, 1, row[1])
        ws_out.write(row_out, 2, req_spec)
        row_out += 1

wb_out.save('output.xls')
```

Unfortunately, if you not familiar with Python there is quite a lot to take in.

The script works by creating an input workbook and an output workbook. For each row in the input, it assumes you will always have 3 columns and that the third one contains one of your three types of specifies. It decides which is in use based on whether or not there is a `-` or a `,` present. It then writes out rows to the output based on this range.

Note, when reading the file in, `xlrd` attempts to guess the format of the cell. For most of your entries, it guesses a string format, but sometimes it wrongly guesses a floating point number. The script tests for this and converts it to a string for consistency. Also `xlrd` uses unicode `u"xxx"` format to store the strings. These need to be converted to numbers to be able to calculate the required ranges.

Comment: Thank you Martin... It helped me a lot...!