# How to get Python script to write to existing sheet

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I am writing a Python script and stuck on one of the early steps.  I am opening an existing sheet and want to add two columns so I have used this:

```
#import the writer
import xlwt
#import the reader
import xlrd
#open the sussex results spreadsheet
book = xlrd.open_workbook('sussex.xlsx')
#open the first sheet
first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
#print the values in the second column of the first sheet
print first_sheet.col_values(1)
#in cell 0,0 (first cell of the first row) write "NIF"
sheet1.write(0, 6, "NIF")
#in cell 0,0 (first cell of the first row) write "Points scored"
sheet1.write(0, 6, "Points scored")
```

On line 12 I get an error:

```
name 'sheet1' is not defined
```

How do I define sheet 1 within the sheet that I have already opened?

Comment: why has this been voted down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sheet1` is never declared. Try changing it to

```
#import the writer
import xlwt
#import the reader
import xlrd
#open the sussex results spreadsheet
book = xlrd.open_workbook('sussex.xlsx')
#open the first sheet
first_sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
#print the values in the second column of the first sheet
print first_sheet.col_values(1)
#in cell 0,0 (first cell of the first row) write "NIF"
first_sheet.write(0, 6, "NIF")
#in cell 0,0 (first cell of the first row) write "Points scored"
first_sheet.write(0, 6, "Points scored")
```

edit: You could also use Pandas to read and write to Excel:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
#open the sussex results spreadsheet, first sheet is used automatically
df = pd.read_excel('sussex.xlsx')

#print the values in the second column of the first sheet
print(df.iloc[:,1])

#Create column 'NIF'
df['NIF'] = np.nan #I don't know what you want to do with this column, so I filled it with NaN's
#in cell 0,7 (first cell of the first row) write "Points scored"
df['Points scored'] = np.nan #I don't know what you want to do with this column, so I filled it with NaN's
<.... Do whatever calculations you want with NIF and Points scored ...> 
# Write output
df.to_excel('sussex.xlsx')
```

Comment: thanks @Niels, that seems to have worked but I have now encountered an issue where it can't write - how would i open the workbook to write to it?

Comment: `Sheet object has no attribute 'write'` is what I get when i try to write in the sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you need to have something like 
`sheet1 = book.sheet_by_index(0)`; because now `sheet1` is not defined.
Also, document is opened using `xlrd` which is reader, and you need to write there values - so document should be opened also using `xlwt`.

Comment: Thanks - I think that may have worked but I now get ''Sheet' object has no attribute 'write'

Comment: Please, check the update answer - you open document using `xlrd`, so that's why `sheet` object does not have `write` method.

Comment: that makes sense - how would i open it using xlwt too?

Comment: Check this example - https://stackoverflow.com/a/40022335/6917446, it is described there...

Comment: so i need to read from sussex.xlsx and write to a new worksheet?

Comment: No, just read the example carefully:
`wb_in = xlrd.open_workbook(r"input.xls")` - open document; 
`sheet_name = wb_in.sheet_names()[0]` - get first sheet`s name from the document; 
`ws_in = wb_in.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)` - select sheet by name; 
`wb_out = xlwt.Workbook()` - init xlwt object, to be able to write data; 
`ws_out = wb_out.add_sheet(sheet_name)` - initialize 1st sheet from the previously opened document, for writing.

Comment: i am officially lost, i added this from lines 8 - 14:

'wb_in = xlrd.open_workbook('sussex.xlsx')
#get first sheet's name from the document
sheet_name = wb_in.sheet_names()[0]
#select sheet by name
ws_in = wb_in.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)
#init xlwt object, to be able to write data
wb_out = xlwt.Workbook
#initialise first sheet from the previously opened document, for writing
ws_out = wb_out.add_sheet(sheet_name)'

Error:

'TypeError: unbound method add_sheet() must be called with Workbook instance as first argument (got unicode instance instead)'